# ListCollectionView filtering DataGrid with MVVM model

Tags: wpf, .net-core, data-binding, datagrid

I'm currently trying to apply a filter of ListCollectionView to a WPF DataGrid.
It should work with my MVVM.

The problem is, that the filter function is only called at the application's start and not after the TextBox is updated (that's the filter).

DataGrid XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DbGrid"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding DbInterruptions}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="314" Margin="2,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1024" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
                 <DataGridTextColumn Header="Timestamp" Binding="{Binding TimeLocal, StringFormat='{}{0:HH:mm:ss.fff}'}"/>
                 <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding TimeLocal, StringFormat='{}{0:dd.MM.yyyy}'}"/>
                 <DataGridTextColumn Header="(Interrupted) Phase" Binding="{Binding Payload.InterruptedPhase}"/>
                 <DataGridTextColumn Header="Event" Binding="{Binding Payload.Event}"/>
                 <DataGridTextColumn Header="Method" Binding="{Binding Payload.Method}"/>
                 <DataGridTextColumn Header="Cutter Id" Binding="{Binding CutterId}"/>
                 <DataGridTextColumn Header="Job" Binding="{Binding Payload.Job}"/>
                 <DataGridTextColumn Header="Event type" Binding="{Binding EventType}"/>
                 <DataGridTextColumn Header="Condition/Beam" Binding="{Binding Payload.Condition}"/>
     </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The ViewModel:

public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
public ObservableCollection DbInterruptions => new ObservableCollection(_mqttModel.JobPhaseHistory);

```
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ReloadFromDatabaseButtonClick();
        _mqttModel.JobHistoryChanged += () => RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(DbInterruptions));

        var filteredDbInterruptions = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(DbInterruptions);
        filteredDbInterruptions.Filter = UserFilter;
    }

    public ICommand ReloadFromDatabase => new RelayCommand(ReloadFromDatabaseButtonClick);

    private void ReloadFromDatabaseButtonClick()
    {
        _mqttModel.RefreshHistoricData();
    }

    private string _jobNameFilter;
    public string JobNameFilter
    {
        get => _jobNameFilter;
        set
        {
            if (_jobNameFilter == value)
                return;
            
            _jobNameFilter = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(JobNameFilter));

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TimeFilter))
                TimeFilter = "";
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(EventNameFilter))
                EventNameFilter = "";

            var filteredDbInterruptions = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(DbInterruptions);
            filteredDbInterruptions.Refresh();
        }
    }

    private string _timeFilter;
    public string TimeFilter
    {
        get => _timeFilter;
        set
        {
            if (_timeFilter == value)
                return;

            _timeFilter = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(TimeFilter));

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(JobNameFilter))
                JobNameFilter = "";
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(EventNameFilter))
                EventNameFilter = "";

            var filteredDbInterruptions = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(DbInterruptions);
            filteredDbInterruptions.Refresh();
        }
    }

    private string _eventNameFilter;
    public string EventNameFilter
    {
        get => _eventNameFilter;
        set
        {
            if (_eventNameFilter == value)
                return;
            
            _eventNameFilter = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(EventNameFilter));

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TimeFilter))
                TimeFilter = "";
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(JobNameFilter))
                JobNameFilter = "";

            var filteredDbInterruptions = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(DbInterruptions);
            filteredDbInterruptions.Refresh();
        }
    }


    private bool UserFilter(object item)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(JobNameFilter) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(TimeFilter) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(EventNameFilter))
        {
            return true;
        }

        var interruption = (item as Interruption);
        if (interruption != null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(JobNameFilter))
            {
                return interruption.Payload.Job.Contains(JobNameFilter);
            }

            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TimeFilter))
            {
                //return interruption.TimeLocal.Equals()
                return true;
            }

            return interruption.Payload.Event.Contains(EventNameFilter);
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

So the filter properties (Name, Event, Time) are those connected to a textbox.
I do not want to do it via Code Behind if not necessary.

Does anyone know, what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know, what I'm doing wrong?

Your property creates a new `ObservableCollection` each time it's called:

```
public ObservableCollection DbInterruptions => new ObservableCollection(_mqttModel.JobPhaseHistory);
```

You should set it *once*:

```
public ObservableCollection DbInterruptions { get; } = new ObservableCollection(_mqttModel.JobPhaseHistory);
```

Comment: Okay, I moved the initialization to the constructor, now nothing's showing up anymore.
The problem with the filter still exists.

Comment: @MarrisKleinert: If you only create one instance, `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView` will return the same view each time. Please provide a [repo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your current issue.